# I can't open steam and steam games on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: steam

When i had ubuntu 14.04 LTS the steam and dota2 were fine and i was playing with hours.

But since when i upgraded to ubuntu 14.10 the steam doesn't open and neither any steam games.

I reinstall it but nothing again! It doesn't show anything. Just doesn't open.

Comment: Start steam from command line and see if it throws errors. Do check your graphics card! Maybe you are not using the one steam wants ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind i tried and says the following:

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1413917607)  
  
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so  
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Comment: That is a video card driver related issue ;) Some hints here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/828934089701456106/?l=dutch

Comment: @Rinzwind sorry but in the link you gave me there are not any answers, only people who describe the issues where they give. And i said i was playing normal with ubuntu 14.04 lts and on 14.10 can't play. And as i see on ubuntu greece on facebook community group there is another one who has the same problem and he just wait.

Comment: That means its a bug that is unresolved as of yet ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on http://chakraos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=13247

You have to do the following on terminal and if it doesn't work:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Go to the folder and found the first file and deleted it. The second file maybe it's not appearing.

Open steam and wait to update.

And it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem.

I fixed my issue by reinstalling Steam by downloading the official Steam .deb pkg & using

`sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb`

Then I switched to the latest video driver (nvidia~>361.42) under

> System Settings>Software & Updates>Additional Drivers

Lastly, I rebooted & that seemed to fix Steam!

Not sure if this played a part in fixing my issue, but I also installed package xserver-xephyr with

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr
```

Comment: I hope my answer helps other Ubuntu users for whom the selected answer does not fix Steam.